# how to take highest value and assign that to generate value

Tags: sql, hierarchy, generate

Hello I have below scenario. I am using ID4 to generate Level 4 and ID3 to generate Level3. So in my ID3 i have two records with NULL. I want my sql to take the value without null and generate same value under level 3 in output file (Yellow Highlighted).

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

here is oneway

```
select Level4 , max(Level3) over (partition by ID4) Level3 ,ID4,ID3
from Inputtable
```

Comment: You are welcome please upvote / accept the answer if it helped